# Synonym for file-size and filesize

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

So in tagging one of my recent questions I noticed that [file-size](/questions/tagged/file-size) and [filesize](/questions/tagged/filesize) are not synonyms of each other. They probably should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently [56 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filesize+php) tagged [filesize](/questions/tagged/filesize) as well as [php](/questions/tagged/php), [where `filesize` is an API call](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php).

That said, I think the [filesize](/questions/tagged/filesize) should be removed first before the synonym is created; a tag for a singular member in a language is *way* too granular.